# C# uninstaller is deleting registry keys I created when installing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am creating registry keys and values when I install my c# program. When I uninstall my proogram, these keys get deleted. I want them to stay there and be persistent. How can I do this. I have tried a few things including setting DeletAtUninstall to be false. Any ideas? I am using visual studio 2010.

[image]

Comment: How can you prove the necessity of what are you planning? Why would someone want to store your registry keys after uninstalling?

Comment: [MSDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9zhk3ba%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) : _If a registry key has values, the key will be removed when all values are removed regardless of the DeleteAtUninstall property setting._ Could that be the case? The same source says: _To meet Microsoft Windows logo requirements, you must set this property to true for your top-level registry keys so that all registry subkeys and values are deleted when the product is uninstalled._

Comment: It is so their configuration can be stored when upgrading to a new version of the software. It is a homebrew project for a friend that I have him uninstall and re-install every time I give him a new build.

Comment: Are you part of those people who love bloating our registry with useless stuff ? :)

Comment: Maybe this should then be the responsibilty of the upgrade installer? Save the settings, run the uninstall, install using the setting. Uninstalling alone should delete the keys!

Comment: What kind of uninstaller are you using?  For example by default InstallShield records everything it did on install and undoes it by default at Uninstall time. This is the proper behavior, but can be over-ridden.

Comment: Why not use configuration files that you store either in the local or roaming profile of the user? Roaming profile is especially handy in an environment where users switch to different "computers".

Answer (score 1):

try this
as shown in trail image

1. select the folder

   2. go to ins Property
      3.and set DeleteATUnInstall=false

[image]

Comment: quote: _I have tried a few things including setting DeletAtUninstall to be false._